# Manual anti-aliasing algorithm in javascript for HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, antialiasing

I want to do some manual anti-aliasing on some text on a canvas. I know how to iterate over the image / colour data, but not exactly how to anti-alias.

From googling around a bit it seems like to do anti-aliasing I need to have an original image which I use as my sample, then pass over the colour data, then for each pixel take an average of the surrounding pixels, then copy this new value into the data for my anti-aliased image.

The bit I'm not sure about is exactly how to 'take an average' of the surrounding pixels.

I have done a [jsFiddle to demostrate what I have done so far](http://jsfiddle.net/6VLNQ/4/). As you will see I am copying the image data from the original canvas, making it negative, then putting it into the second canvas.

If I am being more specific in what I am struggling with, it is **how exactly do you figure out what the surrounding pixels are in a loop which only has one iterator**? And also **is the average just a case of adding the nearest pixels colour vals to the current pixels vals, then dividing by the number of pixels**?

This is the loop in which I wish to manipulate the data:

```
var imgData = originalContext.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
var aliasedData = originalContext.createImageData(width, height);
aliasedData.data.set(imgData.data);

for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    // just make the data negative to show something is happening
    aliasedData.data[i] = 255 - imgData.data[i];
    aliasedData.data[i + 1] = 255 - imgData.data[i + 1];
    aliasedData.data[i + 2] = 255 - imgData.data[i + 2];

    // need to get an average of surrounding pixels here
}
aliasedContext.putImageData(aliasedData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Can you describe how your desired anti-aliasing differs from the automatic anti-aliasing the canvas already does?

Comment: Text anti-aliasing is really poor on canvas, particularly in webkit browsers when using @font-face & woff fonts. The fiddle I did maybe wasn't the best example as it uses Times New, which doesn't look all that bad. I will update my fiddle to show it with a custom font that has jagged edges.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, you will see that with a custom font and smaller font size the anti-aliasing is quite poor